# Moving Nokia content to an Android phone

Tags: contacts, data-transfer

What is the easiest way to move Nokia (Symbian E series) content, such as contacts, inbox, photos, etc. to an Android phone? I can extract a backup from the Nokia but it's in `.nbu` format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By far the easiest way to transfer anything contacts related to an Android phone is via GMail.

When I moved from an old Nokia phone to my Android HTC Magic about a year ago, I downloaded and installed the Nokia Suite of tools for my phone from the Nokia website, installed them, copied my contacts into the Nokia Suite app on the PC, then did an export from the Nokia Suite contacts app to a CSV file. I remember seeing the Noklia-only NBU format as an optin, but if you're in the Contacts-only part of the suite it should also allow the CSV export (as this is also the easiest way to do a one-off import to other apps like Outlook).

At that point you can go into GMail, click the Contacts link, then at the top you should see an "Import" option, use that to upload your CSV file. All that you should lose from this is the contact's photos, but you can easily back up your contact's photos from the Nokia suite, and then just upload them to GMail one by one, or alternatively let Android on the phone sync with Facebook, etc and pull the Contacts photos from there itself.

You might find that if you already had some people in your GMail address book that you'll have a few duplicates now, just tick the relevant Contacts in Gmail and select "Merge these contacts".

For content, such as photos or music, which are probably just files on the Nokia's SD memory card, the easiest way is to attach the phone to a PC, select Data Storage/Transfer Mode on the phone, then open the SD card drive on the PC, drag all the relevant files onto the PC, then attach Android phone, mount SD card and drag all the content into the relevant folders on the Android's SD card.

As for messages, do you mean SMS/MMS text messages? As far as I know there aren't easy ways to transfer those between phone OS's at all (unless you're already doing something like sync'ing them to GMail).

Comment: yup, I mean sms'es

Comment: See this answer to another question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9357/sms-backup-in-android/9434#9434 where it mentions that VeryAndroid SMS backup can be used to transfer SMS's from Nokia to Android.

Answer (score 2):

I have to agree with GAThrawn, that using GMail to transfer your contacts and calender items is probably the best way. But there is an IMHO easier solution to get your data from the Nokia phone to GMail: Nokia's [Mail for Exchange](http://europe.nokia.com/find-products/nokia-for-business/messaging) together with [Google Sync](http://www.google.com/mobile/sync/). Google provides a couple of [help topics](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/topic.py?topic=14298) to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

1. Samsung create an app called [Samsung Smart Switch Mobile](http://www.samsung.com/smartswitch), it support transfer data from Nokia to Samsung mobiles. You can have a try although your phone is not Samsung.
2. Wondershare software named [MobileTrans](http://www.wondershare.net/phone-transfer/) also can transfer data from Nokia to Android.

They can both transfer contacts, messages, photos and videos to Android.

Comment: Neither Smart Switch or MobileTrans worked here. Smart Switch could not see the Nokia back up, & mobileTrans only saw about 20% of the SMS, & none of the contacts, photos or other data

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way that transfer contacts from Nokia to android phone.

Android Devices: Samsung Galaxy S7 edge/S7 /Note 5/S6 edge/S5 | Huawei | Sony | LG | Nexus | HTC | Moto

Nokia: Windows phone/ Symbian/ android

Transfer File: Contacts, Music, Videos, Photos.

[Transfer contacts from Nokia to android phone](https://www.doctor-telephone.com/nokia-transfer/transfer-data-from-nokia-to-android-phone.html)

Comment: What is your connection to this product? If any, you should declare it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I moved content from a Nokia 808 PureView (Belle FP2) to a Samsung Galaxy S8 (Android 7.0 (Nougat)).

## Contacts and calendar

To transfer contacts and calendar, I synced via Gmail (see other answers for details).

## Photos and videos

To transfer photos and videos:

1. Connect the Symbian phone to a computer via USB in mass storage mode and copy the contents of the DCIM folder from the mass storage and memory card
2. To copy to Android

   - from Windows: connect via USB in mass storage mode and copy to the DCIM folder on Android
   - from Mac: install and open [Android File Transfer](https://www.android.com/filetransfer/) then connect via USB and copy to the DCIM folder on Android

## SMS messages

To transfer SMS messages:

1. Open Nokia Suite (I used 3.8.54)
2. Connect your Symbian phone
3. Go to the Messages tab (fourth icon along the top)
4. Click "Sync messages" at the bottom
5. Wait for sync to finish
6. Select File > "Export text messages..." and save as csv
7. Copy CSV to Android phone
8. On Android, install [Anything With Sms from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.toilelibre.libe.athg2sms)
9. Open Anything With Sms
10. From the import tab choose the CSV file

    - The format switched from Nokia Csv to Nokia Suite 3.8
11. Toggle "Default App" for Anything With Sms to be the default app for SMS. This is only temporary for when importing the messages and we'll turn it off later.
12. Click the blue import button in the bottom-right corner
13. Click OK at the info screen about "Change messaging app"
14. Wait for import to finish
15. When finished, click Great! and toggle to turn off default app
    Close Anything With Sms
16. Finally, open your Android messaging app and select the menu > "Mark all as read"