# SMS backup in Android

Tags: sms, backup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I backup and restore SMS Messages?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/how-do-i-backup-and-restore-sms-messages)

How can I make a backup of SMS messages to the SD card in Android 2.2?