# Importing contacts from Nokia C1-01 to Android

Tags: data-transfer

I'm trying to import my contacts from an old Nokia C1-01 to my new Android Motorola G6 Play.  How can I do this?

So far I've tried a Bluetooth connection (connected but couldn't transfer the contacts).

And I've saved my contacts to the Nokia SIM card, but it is the micro-SIM format and I don't think it will fit in the Motorola G6 Play.  Should I cut it to size with a sim card cutter?

I can access the contacts in the phone using the Nokia PC Suite and make a backup of my phone. I can also export the contacts into a CSV. It is combining the first and last name into the "Last Name" field, so I can manually fix this in a spreadsheet and then probably import it into the new phone using Gmail.  I'm following the advice from [this question.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/909/moving-nokia-content-to-an-android-phone)

Comment: Try this, export contacts to .vcf file, then send this via Bluetooth to Moto g6, then import contacts from file.

Comment: I don't think that is possible.  I can export the contacts to the SIM card.  But that and Bluetooth are the only options I see.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't have to cut anything but the plastic around the actual chip, it won't hurt anything to give it a try.

The last time I had a really old phone, I just went over to the nearest cell phone providers store and they transferred over the contacts for me.